# POS Printing in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm googling some good examples on how to use C# to print receipt but I can't find good one. As I'm new to C#, I found examples that are overwhelming.

Basically, the requirement is to print a receipt by clicking a button from a web page. It doesn't need to select a printer like the normal windows print where user is prompted to select a printer then do the print. The receipt should automatically print to an Epson Thermal Printer.

I plan to create the following:

1. Registry entry to call a .vbs
2. VBS to execute the C# program that will do the printing? Not sure if this is possible
3. The actual C# program with printing logic.

Can anyone share some references that I can start with? I already have Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: I also did this task. What I did was, write an TCP Connection Service or web socket connection service and install it on client machine. From your webpage call that service to print receipt automatically.

Comment: @RatsTyagi - do you have samples that I can reference? I'm very new to C# as my first programming language is Java.

Comment: You can use Pos for .NET, it's a bit old but still usable.